# why I can't stream an audio or video stored in dropbox?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

so in my Android app, I can use an exoplayer like this

```
lateinit var player : SimpleExoPlayer!

val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3")
player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build()
player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
playerView.player = player
```

I can stream the audio without any use if I use the code above.

but if I want to use an audio file that have in dropbox, the sound will never play, the code and link is like this

```
val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri("https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbe1kod9t6yuh5j/sample1.m4a")
```

how to solve this ?

Comment: What is the content type of your dropbox url? Have you seen: https://exoplayer.dev/media-items.html#handling-non-standard-file-extensions

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/why-I-can-t-stream-an-audio-stored-in-dropbox-using-Android/td-p/469325 ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**replace www by dl from your link and add ?dl=1 to end**

for example

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/lbe1kod9t6yuh5j/sample1.m4a?dl=1
```

try this. it's work for me.

Comment: Please refer to this help article for the official information on modifying Dropbox shared links for different behaviors, such as direct file data access like this: https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download

Answer (score 1):

Adding **?raw=1** to the end of the URL, worked for me.
Example:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbe1kod9t6yuh5j/sample1.m4a?raw=1
```